Stable calculation of large binomial coefficients in c++
I am looking for a way to reliably calculate large binomial coefficients in c++. My current implementation can handle numbers up to around n=60, but after that f * (n - i) exceeds the limit of long long. I want to go all the way up to n=100, at which point resulting binomial coefficients can be as large as 10E29.
I'd like the precision of the outcome to be as high as possible, but it would be OK to pass a less precise result when the binomial coefficients are very large (e.g., 15 significant digits). But I don't know how to implement that with any fixed return type - long long or other.
long long comb(long long n, long long r) 
{
    long long f = 1; 
    for(auto i = 0; i < r; i++){
        f = (f * (n - i)) / (i + 1);
        }
    return f ; 
}


You can use boost multiprecision.  See this.

As to how to implement this yourself, create a "big number" class that does arithmetic similar to what you did in grade school (digit-by-digit, where each digit is a value in an array of digits).  But that has already been done in boost (and many other third-party libraries), so you would basically be reinventing the wheel if you tried this yourself.

Have you tried to compute them as double? Those have just about the right number of significant digits.

@PaulMcKenzie I think your first comment could be made into a good answer.

You could compute binomial coefficients from Pascal's triangle using only addition. That way your intermediate numbers will never be larger than the result and if you tackle it the right way, you are guaranteed to get the most precise answer even if the mantissa of a double is not large enough.

You could use Pascal's triangle as suggested by @j6t but be aware that direct recursive implementation might not be efficient (possibly large stack usage and re-computation of already computed values). You'll find easily implementations that address these concern (look for memoization and non-recursive versions). In any case, if performance is a concern, you'll always have to benchmark different implementations to be sure of which one is the better for your needs.

you can have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096232/pascal-triangle-recursive-program-optimization-in-c, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pascal-triangle/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709748/pascals-triangle-implementation,...

Another big integer library if you want; I'll be happy to help if you have questions.

If you want a precise answer then use a big integer library (or switch to Python) and calculate the coefficients inductively (NOT recursively) from Pascal’s triangle. If you are happy with floating-point accuracy then either use Pascal’s triangle with doubles or use logarithms to calculate the necessary large factorials and their division, exponentiating back at the end.
